# Error during Websocket handshake with error code 500 using Daphne on Heroku

Tags: heroku, websocket, docker-compose, daphne

So I tried to deploy my docker django chat app to heroku. Previously I had been running the app with runserver command, but now I'm switching to daphne since I need to use websocket but I can't use runserver anymore in order to connect to webserver. After deployment, when I access the app page that shows the chat window this error occurs

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.herokuapp.com/ws/chat/room/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500`

(xxx is actually the url of my app)

Here's a piece of my js code

```
<script>
    var roomName = "{{ room_name|escapejs }}";
    var wsStart = 'ws://';
    if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
                wsStart = 'wss://';
       }
    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        wsStart + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (message + '\n');
    };
```

ws didn't work (error message Django can only use ASGI not websocket) so I changed to wss (according to another post in stackoverflow it's because security reason), which made the other error go away but still can't connect to websocket

This is my run command:
`daphne -p $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2 test_project.asgi:application`

EDIT: if I don't use wss (just use ws instead) this is the error message in js console

`The page at 'https://xxx/chat/m/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://xxx/ws/chat/room/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.`

Extremely appreciate any help, or ideas of what went wrong. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it has just about nothing to do with daphne or my js code that doesn't work. I didn't connect to a heroku-redis at the time and thus was not running redis. Configured REDISTOGO_URL with

```
heroku config --app  <appname> | grep REDISTOGO_URL
```

, changed host in channel_layer from `"hosts": ('redis', 6379),` (something similar) to `"hosts": [os.environ.get('REDISTOGO_URL',('redis', 6379))]` allowed me to connect to heroku redis.